# args4j: in "usage" how to sort Options manually?

Tags: java

In args4j I define options like that:

```
@Option(name="-host",usage="host to connect")
@Option(name="-port",usage="port of the host")
@Option(name="-idle",usage="idle")
```

However when help is displayed args4j always uses alphabetically order so it prints

```
-host - host to connect
-idle - idle
-port - port to connect
```

This is not convient because I want to display mandatory options first. Also I want to set order of options myself because some options (like host and port) should go together.

How can I control order of options in args4j?

I've found the same question asked 3 years ago but not answered http://markmail.org/message/xce6vitw6miywtos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with the current Args4j (at least to my knowledge) - but since it's open source I would encourage you to implement it yourself and try to get the patch in the source for newer releases.

From the source: `org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser`:

```
    // for display purposes, we like the arguments in argument order, but the options in    alphabetical order
     Collections.sort(options, new Comparator<OptionHandler>() {
        public int compare(OptionHandler o1, OptionHandler o2) {
            return o1.option.toString().compareTo(o2.option.toString());
        } 
    });
```

Comment: currently i'm busy with completely other projects (not even Java) but it would be nice if someone else can do that :)

Answer (score 6):

You can set the sorting via the ParserProperties and then use that in the CmdLineParser constructor. If you set the OptionSorter to null, the Option order will be preserved:

```
ParserProperties properties = ParserProperties.defaults();
properties.withOptionSorter(null);
CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(YOUR_OPTIONS_CLASS, properties);
```

So in the question's example you will get:

```
-host - host to connect
-port - port to connect
-idle - idle
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still not solved after 3 years. But there is a workaround.

Since `CmdLineParser` uses a list to store options, and the list is exposed by `getOptions()`, you may get the list and sort it by yourself. Because the list is sorted only in the constructor. You may sort it any time after constructing `CmdLineParser`. Then the output of `printUsage()` is ordered.

This workaround depends on the implementation of `CmdLineParser`, so it's not a good example to emulate. But as a workaround, it works, at least on current version (2.0.28).